# Add and remove attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

This is my buttons:

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
```

this is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        /*** Add attribute ***/
        $("#add").click(function(){
            $("#page_navigation1").attr("id","page_navigation1");
        });     
        /*** Remove attribute ***/
        $("#remove").click(function(){
            $("#page_navigation1").removeAttr("id");
        });     
    });
</script>
```

and this is my html code:

```
<div id="page_navigation1">next</div>
```

My problem is, when I click on Remove button everything is fine and ID will be removed,
but after click on remove button, when I click on Add button, code is not working and nothing happens!

I need to add and remove ID whith this code, but I can just Remove ID, I cant add ID. I need some help for this, and one more thing,

How I can add CSS style for button when button is Active?
like this, when I click on Remove button, I want change button background to red. I need to add css class for add and remove when buttons are active! and I dont know how!

Comment: IIRC, modifying id is not possible, unless the element is created anew.

Comment: You can set the `id` attribute... but you're setting it to the element with the id "add".. if you have no element with id "add" then you can't change its attribute. You need some way of referencing the element.

Comment: could u please explain more? i dont know what r u saying :( and how about css style for buttons when they are active?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's because you've removed the `id` which is how you're finding the element. This line of code is trying to add `id="page_navigation1"` to an element with the `id` named `page_navigation1`, but it doesn't exist (because you deleted the attribute):

```js
$("#page_navigation1").attr("id","page_navigation1");
```

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

If you want to add and remove a class that makes your `<div>` red use:

```js
$( '#page_navigation1' ).addClass( 'red-class' );
```

And:

```js
$( '#page_navigation1' ).removeClass( 'red-class' );
```

Where `red-class` is:

```css
.red-class {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 31):

Once you remove the ID "page_navigation" that element no longer *has* an ID and so cannot be found when you attempt to access it a second time.

The solution is to cache a reference to the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // This reference remains available to the following functions
    // even when the ID is removed.
    var page_navigation = $("#page_navigation1");

    $("#add").click(function(){
        page_navigation.attr("id","page_navigation1");
    });     

    $("#remove").click(function(){
        page_navigation.removeAttr("id");
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 7):

First you to add a class then remove id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("#page_navigation1").addClass("page_navigation");        

 $("#add").click(function(){
        $(".page_navigation").attr("id","page_navigation1");
    });     
    $("#remove").click(function(){
        $(".page_navigation").removeAttr("id");
    });     
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this, you need to save it in a variable first. So you don't need to use id to query this element every time.

```
var el = $("#page_navigation1");

$("#add").click(function(){
  el.attr("id","page_navigation1");
});     

$("#remove").click(function(){
  el.removeAttr("id");
});
```