# asp.net mvc disable submit button if form is invalid

Tags: javascript, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

Is there a way to disable/submit the form submit button if the form has validation errors in such a way that the user can click it only if the form is valid.
I'm using unobtrusive validation with "remote" attribute validation with ASP.Net MVC 4 and razor.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I guess you're looking to do this `client side` ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are doing your validation.  If you are doing it server side with jquery you can add e.preventDefault to the check if it is invalid and the button click won't fire until your conditions are met.  If you are doing server side validation using attributes then you can check model state like

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
}else{
}
```

and if the model state is valid (the data passes all the checks) run one set of code.  If the model state is invalid then just return view to go back to where you started and pass a message with whatever failed for the user.  Hopefully this helps.

Update:

just saw the edit on your comment.  For an ajax call you will want to use prevent default.

```
$('.SubmitButton').on('click', function(e){
   $.ajax({
      //your call
      success: function(result){
          if(result.false){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert(result.message);
          }
      }
   });
});
```

so if the call is successful the submit call will go through.  If it is false then jquery will stop the button click and you can then display a message or do something else.

Comment: Hi Matt and thank you for your answrer. I do server side validation but my Action returns simply a JsonResult with true/false depending on the value. What I need is a js callback to call when ajax validation has completed in order to disable/enable the submit button by using js...right?

Comment: if your validation is working on the server side then I would allow the button to work to get you to the server to check values but then direct them according to the result.  If it is valid then redirect or do whatever comes next.  If invalid then just return View(model) and we usually use viewbag to pass the validation error back to the view for the user

Comment: see my update in the answer for stopping the button click from an ajax call

Comment: mmm I try to be more precise

In my register model I have:
`code`
    [Remote("CheckIfEmailExists", "Register")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
`code`
and CheckIfEmailExists is
`code`
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CheckIfEmailExists(string email)
        {
            //todo: replace with the logic to see if email already exists
            bool result = false;
            return Json(result );
        }
`code`
Everything works finehowever if the validation fails I have no way to disable submit button by JS

Comment: If you fire the ajax call with the button click and use e.preventDefault() on a fail then jquery will stop the button from being clicked.  If you return true then it will allow the button click to continue

Comment: the ajax call is fired automatically when on focusout of a text box...how to intercept the callback by using js?

Comment: for multiple fields I would use hidden fields that store the result of the validation.  on your ajax call I would check if all of the fields are true.  Start the submit button out disabled and when all are true enable that button.  here is a link that goes over adding and removing attributes from elements with jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489037/add-and-remove-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks Matt but my problem is exactly managing the result of ajax validation...I can't find an easy way to fire a callback which will check the result and disable the button accordingly...