# Add dynamic data-attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Is there a way to add a "dynamic" data-attribute to a DOM element with jQuery?

This, for example, doesn't work:

```
var value = 100;

// hoping to add a 'data-100' attribute 
$('div').attr({
  String('data-' + value) :'display: block'
});
```

It throws the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

obs: as far as I know if you sum a string with an integer in JS, it will cast everthing as a String, but anyway I tried with String() because maybe in some language that worked for me once.

This obviously won't work (it will add the 'custom_data' and not the 'data-100' attribute):

```
var custom_data = 'data-100';

// hoping to add a 'data-100' attribute 
$('div').attr({
  custom_data :'display: block'
});
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have type coercion, what makes you think `String()` would be valid ?

Comment: `$('div').attr('data-'+value, 'display: block');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
$('div').attr("data-"+value,"display:block");
```

Your syntax is wrong see [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489037/add-and-remove-attribute-with-jquery)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n5y50nnp/)

Comment: Got it, it shouldn't be inside an object. Though it works that way, except that it tries to cast the key to a string, is that correct?