# Adding and removing anchor attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url, for example:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#globalModal" id="apply_to_job" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL');?>jobs/apply_to_job/<?php echo System::escape($this->job->job_id); ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo System::translate("Apply for job"); ?></a>
```

When clicking this HREF it will bring up a modal with other stuff. Once that complete that, I want to re-design the anchor attributes by removing the:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#globalModal"
```

Once they click the new HREF again, I want to add the above back to the anchor attributes

This is the jquery I have, so how can I remove the data-toggle stuff?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#apply_to_job_form').on('submit', function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            success:function(data){
                if(!data.success){
                    $.notify(data.error, "error");
                }else{
                    $.notify(data.success, "success");
                    $('#globalModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#apply_to_job').removeClass("btn-primary");
                    $('#apply_to_job').addClass("btn-danger");
                    $('#apply_to_job').attr("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>jobs/cancel_application/" + $('#job_id').val());
                    $('#apply_to_job').text("<?php echo System::escape("Cancel applicaiton"); ?>");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see, it changes the href but doesn't remove the data-toggle.

Comment: The element is not an "HREF". It's an anchor.

Comment: I know. I went to edit, but you already editted.

Comment: The question body needs work still.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `data-toggle` attribute? If so you do `$("#apply_to_job").removeAttr("data-toggle");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add and remove attribute with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489037/add-and-remove-attribute-with-jquery)

Comment: There's a PHP open tag in there. Is this inside of a PHP file (ie, embedded part of a page) or is this a plain script file? (The latter will cause issues)

Comment: @Katana314 Where? I can't see one?

Comment: @randommman `("href", "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these two lines of code in the else section of your jquery function

```
$("#apply_to_job").removeAttr("data-toggle");
$("#apply_to_job").removeAttr("data-target");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the `data-toggle="modal"` then you can use jQuery `removeAttr()` function which gave you @jmb.mage in the above.

Here's the relevant example which I hope you find helpful:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#apply_to_job_form').on('submit', function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),

            success:function(data){
                if(!data.success){
                    $.notify(data.error, "error");
                }else{
                    $('a#apply_to_job').removeAttr('data-toggle');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```