# How to add attribute to an element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hello I am new to this and I want to add the attribute `data-gallery` to all the `img` elements inside `div#gallery-1`. How to do this using jQuery?
I have tried all of the answers but I get the "`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`" error. I am not a web developer but I want to know about that.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Also, lots of examples out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995628/adding-attribute-in-jquery and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489037/add-and-remove-attribute-with-jquery

Comment: Check [Adding data attribute to DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935191/adding-data-attribute-to-dom)

Comment: did you add a reference to jquery before your script?

Comment: @Webpandit yes of course there is a reference to jquery 1.12.4

Answer (score 5):

No need to use `each` or `find`.

```
// set
$("#gallery-1 img").attr("data-gallery", "value");

// get
$("#gallery-1 img").attr("data-gallery");
```

You can even use `data`. That is not an visible attribute in  your code, it's stored in an jQuery object, but has the same effect.

```
// set
$("#gallery-1 img").data("gallery", "value");

// get
$("#gallery-1 img").data("gallery");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("#gallery-1").find('img').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('data-gallery', '');
 })
```

Comment: Do we really need .each(function() for #gallery-1? #gallery-1 is an id and cannot be more than one in that page...

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#gallery-1").find("img").attr("data-gallery", "");
```

Comment: I think this is just a getter, for a setter you need to add a second param.

Comment: If you only set one parameter it will return the value in this attribute

Comment: you can alse use `.data('gallery')` to get and set values.